# merge two associative arrays in one associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge many different assoc arrays in one array but in the form of assoc array. Like i have different arrays like this

```
Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => ghi )
Array ( [0] => jkl [1] => mno [2] => pqr )
.
.
.
```

and want to make an array like

```
array
  0 => 
    array 
      0 => string 'abc' 
      1 => string 'def' 
      2 => string 'ghi' 
  1 => 
    array 
      0 => string 'jkl' 
      1 => string 'mno' 
      2 => string 'pqr' 
.
.
.`
.
```

i am getting these arrays from a csv file. Please help. Thanks

Comment: PHP has a lot of array functions described in the manual...have you looked through any of them? I think you will find there is a native function to do this.

Comment: Yes i tried using many of them but all of them simply merges the array but not like what i want. I give a check again but i am sure none was working.

Comment: Have you tried `array_merge_recursive`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to merge the arrays... you just want to make a multidimensional array i.e. an array of arrays. [See the difference here](http://www.w3resource.com/php/data-types/arrays.php).

You are creating the initial arrays from the csv file, but I'll create them here for completeness:

```
$array1 = array ( "0" => "abc", "1" => "def", "2" => "ghi" );
$array2 = array ( "0" => "jkl", "1" => "mno", "2" => "pqr" );
```

Then all you need to do is create an array with those arrays as the values, depending on what works with the rest of your code, e.g.

```
$multiarray = array();
$multiarray["0"] = $array1;
$multiarray["1"] = $array2;
```

*or*

```
$multiarray = array ( "0" => $array1, "1" => $array2 );
```

If you `print_r ($multiarray);`, it will look like the example in your question.

By the way, the examples you have given are not associative arrays, but I've treated them as if they are in case you do actually need them.
If your arrays are just standard indexed arrays, then you don't need to specify the key, e.g.

```
$array1 = new array("abc", "def", "ghi");
etc
$multiarray[] = $array1;
$multiarray[] = $array2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I provide another point of view, which is lest optimized for the task in itself  as I see it but might be useful in some context.

```
$array = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
$array2 = array('jkl', 'mno', 'pqr');

function gather(... $array){return $array;}

my_print_r(gather($array, $array2));
```

That function uses the splat operator, which natively gathers whatever arguments are sent to the function as entries in an array, called array in that example. We can do whatever we want with array in that function, but just by retuning it, it does what you asked for.